# Resources for $\phi^4$ and $\phi^3$ theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, resource-recommendations

I have recently completed a first course on Quantum Field Theory, referring primarily to the textbooks by Schwartz and Blundell & Lancaster. I now want to explore in more detail the scalar field theories, in particular, the $\phi^4$ and $\phi^3$ theories. For this, I would like to know about some (possibly exhaustive) references on these topics.

In particular, I am not only looking at resources treating regularization schemes at one- and two-loops, but also applications of these theories to diverse physical phenomena. In fact, I would welcome suggestions for more than one resource which focus on different aspects of these theories.

Comment: "Critical Properties of $phi^4$ theories" by Kleinert and Frohlinde is an exhaustive overview of extracting critical exponents of the O($N$) universality classes from $phi$^4 theory.

Comment: Thanks for this reference. Can you suggest something similar for $\phi^3$ theories?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can find a pretty complete treatment of the renormalization of $\phi^3$ and $\phi^4$ ($\phi^3$ is done in 4 and 6 dimensions) in George Sterman's book (Quantum Field Theory), chapter 10. No application to physical systems though.